# getElementsByTagName returning strings

Tags: javascript

My ultimate goal here is to get a list of radiobuttons and check/uncheck them. Here is my code:

```
    for (var radio in document.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
        if(typeof (radio) != "string")
            alert(radio);
    }
```

The `alert` never gets called.

The call to document.getElementsByTagName returns a list of strings numbered from 0 to the length of the list, so all of their properties (type, id, etc) are undefined and I can't really do much with them.

Am I doing something wrong here? Why aren't objects being returned for these elements?

This is in firefox 4 and chrome, if that helps.

Comment: Are you trying find if `document.getElementsByTagName('input').radio` is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` object, which is `Array`-*like* in the sense that it prototypes arbitrary numeric indices onto it.

You should **not** use a `for..in` loop to enumerate through a `NodeList`.

Why?

Because `for..in` iterates through all of the properties of an object, which will cause extra unwanted properties that exist in `NodeList` as well as the arbitrary indices prototyped 
onto it (which, by the way are properties too.)

Since you are iterating through the indices, you are guaranteed not to get any object other than a `DOMElement` object. Therefore, you do not need the `typeof` check.

So, I think you meant to do this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, j = els.length; i < j; i++) {
   alert(els[i]);
}
```

Or, you can also do this, but I don't recommend it:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var index in els) {
   if(els.hasOwnProperty(index) && typeof index === 'number') {
      //we have an element
      alert(els[index]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Will a `typeof DOMElement` ever evaluate to `string`?

Comment: I think you meant a `NodeList` of DOM elements, subtlely different from an array - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D

Comment: @Russ Wow, can't believe I forgot about that. Updated, thanks

Comment: @MarcelKoppel Never, but `typeof(typeof DOMElement)` always will. ;-)

Comment: As you might be able to tell, I'm a .NET developer :] Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a normal for loop. for ( x in obj ) loops over the properties of the object, not the actual elements of the array.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for ( var i=0; i<els.length; i++ ) {
    var radio = els[i];
    if ( typeof(radio) != "string" ) {
        alert(radio);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not completely true, you *can* use a `for … in` loop to iterate over array elements, but you'll probably get more elements than desired (caused by prototype chaining).

Comment: BTW, `typeof(radio)` (you can omit the parentheses) will always evaluate to `object`, as all `HTMLElements` do.

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/azw8W/2/)**

As others have stated, `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList` object and you need to iterate through it differently. Here are some ways to accomplish your ultimate goal of checking/unchecking the radios.

**With jQuery**

```
$.each($('input[type="radio"]'), function () {
        if (true) // Your condition for checking true
           $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        else  
           $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

**Without jQuery**

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var input = inputs.item(i);
    if(input.type == "radio")
        if (true) // Your condition for checking true
           input.checked = "checked";
        else
           input.removeAttribute("checked");
    }
}
```